# Failing to create REST Web Service with Maven, Tomcat 7 on Netbeans

Tags: rest, maven, tomcat, netbeans, http-status-code-404

I've tried to solve the problem that i've mentioned above but it seems i can't find the problem i have. I am trying to create a RESTful Web Service to get one simple text as a result. I've used some code from the internet and tried to adapt to get the simplest Web Service ever, but i failed >_

I know i must have forgotten something important, but i cannot find it. Thus, i appreciate your advice with this problem.

My code looks like this:
**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-xml</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <name>rest-xml-example</name>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
     version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>REST XML Example</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>test</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST XML Example</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

A Java Class **RESTfulHelloWorld.java**

```
package ub;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class RESTfulHelloWorld {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public Response getStartingPage() {
        String output = "<h1>Hello World!<h1>"
            + "<p>RESTful Service is running ... <br>Ping @ " + new Date().toString() + "</p<br>";
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }
}
```

And my project structure looks like this:
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaLKr.jpg)

My result (no matter which URI i use) is **HTTP 404 - /rest-xml**. The directory structure from webapps is like this:
[webapps dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQR4S.jpg)

Any ideas? thank you very much for your help.

Best Regards

Comment: `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` should be `jersey.config.server.provider.packages`. The former is for Jersey 1.x. Anything using `com.sun.jersey`, you will know is 1.x, which is not compatible with 2.x

Comment: Oh, thank you! Once i changed it, the path localhost:8080/rest-xml/rest/hello fetched the right results! Thank you very much, i was going crazy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages should be jersey.config.server.provider.packages. The former is for Jersey 1.x. Anything using com.sun.jersey, you will know is 1.x, which is not compatible with 2.x – Paul Samsotha Aug 15 '17 at 10:14